# How to store a java.util.Date object in MySQL with accuracy down to a second?

Tags: mysql

I know it's a common question but I couldn't find how to store a `java.util.Date` object in MySQL.

Is it possible? if not what kind of solution you reccomand me since I need this accurate time stored in my MySQL database.

Comment: Dates are just a point in time and do not have a format.  When you convert a Date to a String you apply a format to determine how this is done.  Could you clarify what you are trying to do without using the word format?

Comment: what the problem with `new Date()`?

Comment: I wan't a java Date object that contains year,month,day,hour,minute.

Comment: use **GregorianCalendar**, `new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute)` is depricated.

Comment: `java.util.Date` contains that information. What exactly are your trying to do?

Comment: java.util.Date object gives you date and time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Simply call `Calendar.getInstance()` to grab yourself an instance, then you can use `get(Calendar.YEAR);` to get the year, `get(Calendar.DAY);` to get the day, and so on.

You can set the time in a similar way by using the `set()` method.

If you want to convert this to a date object, use the `getTime();` method, and if you want to format the date into a string then have a look at `SimpleDateFormat`.

As a general example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2012, 11, 1, 10, 10); //Sets c to 10:10, 1st December 2012
Date date = c.getTime(); //If you want the calendar object as a date
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY); //Get the current day in the calendar as an integer
String format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss DD-MM-YYYY").format(c.getTime()); //Print date as a string
```

You can also use a `SimpleDateFormat` object to parse the date like so:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss DD-MM-YYYY").parse("10:10:00 01-12-12");
```

If you're using the `SimpleDateFormat` more than once, then best to have it as a separate variable rather than keep recreating it.

Comment: That's perfect but it gives me date as text, is it possible to get it as number?

Comment: @ImriPersiado How do you mean as a number? As the code there shows, use the `get()` method to get the different parts of the current date as an integer.

Comment: Why not just using `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` and skip the calendar crap interface completely?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If all he wanted to do was print a date as a string I would have done - but the original question was rather unclear (and the question has now been edited so heavily this answer looks irrelevant...)

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` also creates `Date` instances from strings with the `.parse()` method, it isn't just about printing. In other comments he mentions trying to store the results in MySQL, hence the editing of the question to reflect the discussion and missing information in attempt to not get the question closed as it was worded.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date() ;
        System.out.println(date);
        // or use calendar
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 13);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        date = cal.getTime();
}
```

gives you `Sun Jan 13 23:48:59 IST 2013`

Comment: Just using `System.out.println()` works of course to print out a date in the default format, but I'd advocate the use of `SimpleDateFormat` to give more control over how the date is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

If you, as I suspect, rather want to convert a string to a date-object, then you could still use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
Date d = dateFormat.parse("2011-02-21 23:22:10");
```

Comment: That's nice but I need a Date object since I'm storing this information in a mysql db as Date.

Comment: @ImriPersiado The date object is there, constructed where it says `new Date()`!

Comment: So your question is how to set a date-object with a specific date and time?

Comment: here is a Date api [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should not use a `Date` object, `java.util.Dat`e is not immutable;
Far better is to use a primitive `long`, which stores the date as utc time. (Number of  milliseconds since midnight 1.1.1970 UT) This is independent of local time, daytime savings. etc.

You get the `long` value via method `getTimestamp()` from a temporary `Date` object. (Or directly or indirectly from `GregorianCalendar`)

From a long utc timestamp you can easily create any Date object you need (e.g in DB).

If you need local time, things get far more complex. So best advise is to use local time only for dispaly (e.g UI) purpose, and transfor to local time immedeatly before display. Better not  to store a Date in local time)

Answer (score -2):

```
class Date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    int hour;
    int minute;

    public Date(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute){
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
    }

}
```

Now you can create instances of this, and pass it along. Additionally, you can create getters/setters or a toString function.

Comment: Duplicating trivial functionality that's already provided in the standard APIs isn't a good call in my book...